# Agregar una frase a un texto previamente copiado

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un script que me detecta el evento copy y le agrega a ese texto copiado una frase al portapapeles.

Pero, al pegar ese texto, no funciona. Creo que el evento no se está disparando correctamente

Aquí el código

```
// Escucha de evento.
document.addEventListener("copy", function (event) {
  // frase a agregar,
  var phrase = "\n\nTexto extraído de ";
  // se obtiene la URL de la página actual.
  var url = window.location.href;
  // se obtiene texto seleccionado
  var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();

  // Si el texto seleccionado ya incluye la frase o está vacío, no se agrega nada al portapapeles.
  if (!selectedText || selectedText.includes(phrase)) {
    return;
  }

  // Se obtiene el texto copiado
  var copiedText = event.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");

  // Se añade la frase al texto copiado.
  copiedText += phrase;

  // Se añade la URL al texto copiado y la frase.
  copiedText += " (de " + url + ")";

  // Se añade todo al portapapeles.
  event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", copiedText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que hay ciertas dificultades con el manejo del evento que se provee por el event listener de copy. En vez de utilizar este te recomiendo usar el api de `navigator`

```js
document.addEventListener("copy", async (event) => {
  const phrase = "\n\nTexto extraído de ";
  // se obtiene la URL de la página actual.
  const url = window.location.href;
  // se obtiene texto seleccionado
  const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();

  // Si el texto seleccionado ya incluye la frase o está vacío, no se agrega nada al portapapeles.
  if (!selectedText || selectedText.includes(phrase)) {
    return;
  }

  let copiedText = await navigator.clipboard.readText();

  // Se añade la frase al texto copiado.
  copiedText += phrase;

  // Se añade la URL al texto copiado y la frase.
  copiedText += " (de " + url + ")";

  // Se añade todo al portapapeles.
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copiedText);
});
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">
  texto a copiar
</textarea>
```

Acá usamos dos funciones asíncronas:

- readText
- writeText

Comment: Hola. Exactamente no es copiar el textode un textarea, sino, seleccionar texto de una página que estoy leyendo y al copiarlo, que me aparezca ese texto adicional. Ese código funcionaría con el textarea, pero al probarlo de la manera que planteo, no funciona. Saludos

Comment: Este codigo es generico, aplica siempre que se ejecute el evento de copia en el navegador, no solo en textareas. Si no es lo que buscas en concreto te recomiendo hacer ajustes a los detalles de tu pregunta y plantear adecuadamente lo que necesitas.

Comment: Te comprendo, pero si bien debería funcionar, al disparar el evento copy no pasa nada. Creo que es el navegador mismo quien me está bloqueando

Comment: Si, el API `navigator` requiere que el usuario de permisos a la página para modificar su portapapeles, esto hace referencia a una característica de seguridad